# Changing default drivers using Capybara per scenario

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have written a small block that will launch Google Chrome when I set a tag `@chrome` above a scenario within a feature file.

```
Before ('@chrome') do

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
      Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
        :browser => :chrome,
        desired_capabilities: {
        'chromeOptions' => {
          'args' => %w{ window-size=1920,1080 }
        }
      }
    )
      end
  end
```

The problem I have is that all subsequent scenarios within the feature file will also run in Chrome, even when the tag isn't set for them.

Is there a way to add to it to say revert back to Poltergeist once I'm done. I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
  After do |scenario|


 if @chrome == true
    Capybara.register_driver = :poltergeist
          Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
              app,
              phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],
              window_size: [1280, 1024],
              js_errors: false,
              debug: false
          )
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance for any help you might have

Comment: have you tried something like https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver ? `Capybara.current_driver =`

Comment: I tried that along with Capybara.default_driver. No joy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara already provides this behavior [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb) . To use it you just need to require it and register a driver with the tag name you want to use. This would usually be in your env.rb/custom_env.rb

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    browser: :chrome,
    ...
  )
end
```

The important thing is the name you use to register the driver has to match the tag used (in this case @chrome).  It also shows you shouldn't be changing Capybara.default_driver on a test by test basis, that's what Capybara.current_driver is for.  You also shouldn't be registering a new driver every scenario, register_driver is meant to be called once for each driver configuration you will need and then referenced by name later.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's a big help